# Status of files with git on a mac

Tags: git, macos

I have recently started using git on a mac and wanting to know how you can tell easily which files have been edited and not committed.

On my windows computer, through explorer, each file has a symbol to tell you if it has been updated since last commit.  At a glance it is very easy to tell which folders are being tracked and their status, and which files within folders etc.

I'm looking for a OSX equivalent if one exists.

EDIT: Sébastien has pointed out that I most likely have something installed to get the Windows integration.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you installed something like [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) on windows to get windows explorer integration. This may help: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools

Comment: Thanks Sébastien - I don't recall installing anything to get the Windows Explorer integration - however that certainly doesn't mean I didn't have such installed.  Thanks for the link - I'll look through and see if I can find something that gives the result I'm after.

Comment: If you use `eclipse IDE`, then you can find `General -> Editor -> Text Editors -> quick diff`, Select `git version` to see the diff immediately.     If you want to see number of files changed you can use command `git status -s`. If you need tool for both, you can use `gitlab` or `source-tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't any good Git integration with OS X Finder, at least not as good as something like TortoiseGit. Some things that definitely help and work well are:

[SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/): A graphical client, allowing you to interact with your local and remote Git repositories. This is great - I use it all the time, and it's free.

I also recommend that you familiarize yourself with the OS X command line/Terminal and use Git from there. I find that many Git commands are faster to use from command line. Typing `git pull` takes less time than opening a Git client and selecting the menu entry there.

When using the command line for Git, update your shell to use one of the following, they will show Git status information (changed files, incoming/outgoing changes) in your prompt:

- [oh-my-git](https://github.com/arialdomartini/oh-my-git): A nice prompt for Git repositories.
- [Bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it): A more general Bash framework with lots of functionality, including Shell themes with Git support. My favorite is the `powerline-multiline` theme. (*Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of Bash-it*)

These are incredibly useful, and learning how to use the command line will definitely pay off in the long run.